# Really Struggling in electronics. What to do?

Tags: resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, education, electronics, electrical-engineering

This is my first post so please go easy on me.

Okay. Let me introduce myself. I am a first year undergrad CS student who has to study basic electronic course for one semester. As the title says, I am really falling behind in the course.Believe me, My lecturer doesn't teaches anything properly. She just write the horrifying formulae on the board without explaining the concepts involved in them. The course has already gone a great length and I am greatly confused.
It's not that I don't study. I study a lot but I am really weak in electronics.
SO PLEASE suggest me some some book/video series that might be able to  help me get through the course. We are currently learning about BJTs and it's acting like a nightmare for me. Please suggest me some course/book/video to understand it first.

In BJTs,we are required to study all of the configurations(common emitter,base,collector),various opreating region(active,saturation,cutoff,breakdown) and something relating opreating point(with the help of q point) and load line analysis .I really didn't understood that topic.Also there are some other topics like analysis of transistor using h model and feedback oscillators.As I already said,this is an introductory course in electronics so there is no need to go in too much depth in the topics.A nice lesson of concepts involved will be enough.Help.

Comment: Why don't you find the concepts e.g. on Wikipedia? Like on pages such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor

Comment: Maybe I should have linked to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor - See also this 20-minute video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YAmmUE-0jA - Or this 5-minute video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CrcRabTQ0s

Comment: It sounds like you could use a good book.  It's hard to make a recommendation without knowing you, but a favorite of mine is "Art of Electronics" by Horowitz and Hill.

Comment: Are you the only student in your class? How about getting together with a bunch of others and working trough the materials as a group? I bet there is more than one student there who can follow the class just fine and who could help you. That's a way better strategy for college than hanging around here.

Comment: You are probably right.I should have asked more specifically.It's a basic electronic course so I don't need to go into too much depth about the topics.I just need a book which caters to my basic needs of clear concepts.
Right now,we are being taught the bipolar junction transistor topic.We have to learn about the various configurations(common emitter,base,collector),regions of opreation(active,saturation,cutoff and breakdown) and about opreation point or Q point using load line analysis.I don't really understand that.There are some other topics which I am forgetting right now.Please help me.

Comment: Why not go to your lecturer and ask them for help? I'm sure if you did they'd be more obligated to go into depth.

Comment: Like I already said,I am not really able to grasp what my lecturer tells in the class(neither do most of the other students but they simply don't care whether they understand the topic or not).I tried re asking the doubts in the class itself but got even more confused due to the absurd explanations given to me.Believe me,I am not exaggerating.I have tried all what I could.Besides,my core branch is Computer Science.That's where I should be expending a major chuck of time,Don't I?Please help.I will most likely upload my course overview sheet in a day or two.Till then,please help me with BJTS.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226955/2451 and links therein.